# Can Bot ConversationData properties get overwritten even if they are set exactly once?

Tags: botframework

We are using the [BotBuilder-Azure](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure) extension to persist various properties representing a conversation wide context in the bot's `Conversation` data bag using standard `Get..Data` and `Set..Data` methods mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#bot-state-methods).

It seems that sometimes the data bag is getting overwritten, after being set correctly. It happens even for properties we are only setting once in the whole conversation.

e.g.

1. invoke event sets `isInitialized = true` once at start of conversation
2. message event 1 sets `name = "John"`
3. message event 1 gets `isInitialized = true`, `name = "John"`
4. message event 2 and all later message gets `isInitialized = false`, `name = null`

We are using `LastWriteWins` policy as follows. We assume that even if 2 write events happen out of order, only the property being written both time would get overwritten and the property which is set only once in the whole flow should not get overwritten ever. Isn't this assumption valid?

```
builder.Register(c => 
    new CachingBotDataStore(store, CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.LastWriteWins))
        .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
        .AsSelf()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: You should add a code for your example to see if your implementation looks right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We assume that even if 2 write events happen out of order, only the property being written both time would get overwritten and the property which is set only once in the whole flow should not get overwritten ever. Isn't this assumption valid?

No
The entire databag is re-written, so any properties in ConversationData will contain the values for whatever was last saved

this [Semaphore](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Base/Scope.cs#L64) ensures messages on a single machine are processed in the order the server receives them keyed on conversation ID and writes to the conversation or private conversation bags will not conflict.  Once a bot is scaled sideways, this guarantee does not exist anymore.

For Data specific to the user use `UserData`.  The conversation ID is not guaranteed to persist for the duration of the whole conversation (in most cases) no matter how you interpret "whole conversation".  How the conversation ID is determined is different for every channel. In some cases, you may even see a new conversation for every message.  I would guess this is why you are seeing this behavior, a new conversation ID will not contain the `ConversationData` from another conversation with the same user.

However, the user ID is generally going to be guaranteed in most channels.  There may be some exceptions to this, but for the most part this will be true.

You did not include any information about the channel(s) you are using so I am trying to be as general as possible.

Comment: no problem I just made some updates that explain some more pieces of this.

Comment: Thanks @JasonSowers. I am using the Skype channel and I am able to see the Activity.Conversation.Id is same throughout the whole conversation with the single user.My question was whether updating one property in the data bag only updates that property in CosmosDB or the BotBuilder, updates the whole bag it loaded from DB at the start of the request

I will try to get code example. But this issue was hard to reproduce, as the data was getting overwritten only sometimes, which I assume happens when different instances of our bot tried to write to the same data bag for the same conversation

Comment: Thanks, posted only half of my reply accidentally and timed out editing it. I got the answer from your update. Thanks

Comment: is it feasible to enhance BotBuilder to only push the 'dirty' properties back to CosmosDB instead of the whole data bag? I am assuming having a bot scaled sideways would be the norm in production systems

Comment: It's not impossible, but the azure package does not natively do it, or have a configuration for it.